# Why can't I use a function I pass down for onTap in a child widget?

Tags: flutter

I have a problem using a function from a parent widget.

This is the file where I want to use the function:
https://github.com/sketchbuch/flutter-naughts-and-crosses/blob/master/lib/widgets/game/board.dart

And this is where it is defined:
https://github.com/sketchbuch/flutter-naughts-and-crosses/blob/master/lib/screens/game.dart

The function sets the state in the parent widget and needs to take an index number as an argument but flutter won't let me use it like this.

VSC shows an error: "The expression here has a type of 'void', and therefore can't be used." but I'm not to sure exactly how to fix the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is because of incorrect use of the `=>` operator

```
  onTap: () => {setSquare(1)}
```

What you are doing here is returning an object that contains the function. Using proper dart syntax, you can write it as:

```
  onTap: () {setSquare(1);}
```

or

```
  onTap: () => setSquare(1),
```